# Finding Smallest x and y to Satisfy Equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Find the smallest natural numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $$7^2x=5^3y$$
I'm unsure how to proceed with this question. Could someone explain the process for determining the answer?

**Added from the comments:**

$x=5^3$ would satisfy $5^3$ divides $7^2x$

Comment: $5^3$ divides $7^2x$, and $\gcd(5^3, 7^2) = 1$, therefore...

Comment: $x=5^3$ would satisfy $5^3$ divides $7^2x$

Comment: right... so what would that make $y$?

Comment: You'll also need some argument that $x=5^3$ is the *smallest* possible $x$.  You can do this using unique prime factorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic,
$$7^2x=5^3y=7^25^3z,$$ as the factorization must include both $7^2$ and $5^3$.

It turns out that the smallest possible value, $z=1$ gives the solution.

Answer (score 1):

First consider left side. $5^3$ divides right side, so $5^3$ must also divides left side. Now $7^2$ and $5^3$ are relatively prime, so $5^3$ occurs in $x$, in other word:

$$x=5^3 \cdot x'$$

For some natural $x'$. $x'$ is natural, so $x' \geq 1$, so:

$$x=5^3 \cdot x' \geq 5^3$$

The same way we get:

$$y \geq 7^2$$

But if we put $x=5^3$ and $y=7^2$ the equation is satisfied, so $x,y$ are the smallest possible solutions.